# Rails: How to use an array in a form, when using a form object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've taken advice from http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ and created a form object.

It begins:

```
class CreatorSignup
include Virtus.model

extend ActiveModel::Naming
include ActiveModel::Conversion
include ActiveModel::Validations

attr_reader :user
attr_reader :writing_sample

attribute :sample_urls, Array[String]
```

`:sample_urls` will be used to create `:writing_samples`:

```
  sample_urls.each do |sample_url|
    @user.writing_samples.create!(url: sample_url)
  end
```

The problem is, I don't know how to populate the form with a field for each item in the `sample_urls` array.

My `#new` action:

```
def new
  @signup = CreatorSignup.new
  @signup.sample_urls = Array.new(5)
end
```

The form is built like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :sample_urls do |sample_f| %>
  <%= sample_f.text_field :url %>
<% end %>
```

Instead of five fields, I get just the one.

Have I got anything noticeably wrong. How can I get a field for each item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you're trying to store more than one object (in your case sample url's) you would have a record for each one instead of saving them in an array. For example, a signup would have many sample urls. This would make your f.fields_for :sample_urls work because there are multiple sample url records.

Comment: The problem I have here is that `CreatorSignup` is not based on `ApplicationRecord`. I need a way to make that `has_many` relationship.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902263/rails-how-to-use-an-array-in-a-form-when-using-a-form-object/43902546#43902546 offers a solution.